# Class design to avoid need for list of base classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, rtti

I'm currently in the design phase of a class library and stumbled up on a question similar to "[Managing diverse classes with a central manager without RTTI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128475/managing-diverse-classes-with-a-central-manager-without-rtti)" or "[pattern to avoid dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949110/pattern-to-avoid-dynamic-cast)".

Imagine there is a class hierarchy with a base class *Base* and two classes *DerivedA* and *DerivedB* that are subclasses of *Base*. Somewhere in my library there will be a class that needs to hold lists of objects of both types *DerivedA* and *DerivedB*. Further suppose that this class will need to perform actions on both types depending on the type. Obviously I will use virtual functions here to implement this behavior. But what if I will need the managing class to give me all objects of type *DerivedA*?

Is this an indicator of a bad class design because I have the need to perform actions only on a subset of the class hierarchy?

Or does it just mean that my managing class should not use a list of *Base* but two lists - one for *DerivedA* and one for *DerivedB*? So in case I need to perform an action on both types I would have to iterate over two lists. In my case the probability that there will be a need to add new subclasses to the hierarchy is quite low and the current number is around 3 or 4 subclasses.

Comment: Why do you want all objects of type `DerivedA`? Maybe there's another way of achieving what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what if I will need the managing class to give me all objects of
>   type DerivedA?
>
> Is this an indicator of a bad class design because I have the need to
>   perform actions only on a subset of the class hierarchy?

More likely yes than no. If you often need to do this, then it makes sense to question whether the hierarchy makes sense. In that case, you should separate this into two unrelated lists.

Another possible approach is to also handle it through virtual methods, where e.g. `DeriveB` will have a no-op implementation for methods which don't affect that. It is hard to tell without knowing more information.

Comment: I'd be careful with judging - imagine a list of controls in a window. The list holds only base classes, but controls usually differ greatly in their behavior and interfaces. Seeking through controls for specific types does not seem to be anything bad (for example to perform an operation on all window controls or ones displaying text etc.). Also, I'd prefer a bool result rather than no-op - caller would be informed, that DerivedB did not perform any action. Though, in certain situations, no-op is acceptable.

Comment: @Spook - that why I wrote *More likely yes than no*. For controls, the problem is that you don't control implementation so you have no choice. `bool` suggestion is too specific, IMO - it implies that you know at the base of the hierarchy whether you expect this to be supported in derived types, and this brings up a question why having it at all if you expect that derived types don't need it.

Comment: @ZdeskavVojkovic Well, you could say that also to a solution with no-op :) bool only provides class user with information, if action was performed or not. And I did not neglected you saying *more likely yes than no*. I merely wanted to point out, that without context it's hard to judge.

Comment: bool prevents methods from having a return value related to business logic if needed. base class should not care whether the function was performed (in general, except for methods where this is whole purpose). Why would SetText() return true/false, even if it is called on `Panel` which shows no text? 'no-op' is implementation detail, returning bool is not.

Comment: This can be achieved by a `bool Supports(Action a)` and throwing exception if called method is unsupported. Still, I might want to know, if a call succeeded or was ignored by the callee.

Comment: IMO, `bool Supports(Action a)` is often just hidden checking of the type of the object (granted, it checks for functionality instead of implementation), but sometimes it makes sense. I do have a couple of those, too :)

Answer (score 2):

It certainly is a sign of bad design if you store (pointers to) objects together that have to be handled differently.

You could however just implement this differing behaviour as an empty function in the base class or use the visitor pattern.

Comment: What if 98% of their functionality is common and they differ only in 2%? And what would you say about holding controls (which differ greatly) on common list held by the window in many frameworks? You cannot judge, whether this is a good idea or a bad one without knowing the context, -1 for that.

Comment: Well yes, I can :) If something is stored together and is accessed using pointers it should behave the same. Why not store controls in a separate list?

Comment: Show me the visual framework, which stores different visual controls on different lists (in the window). And the controls are stored by pointers.

Comment: My visual framework is `iostream` most of the time, so I can't help you out there. Just remember, that the asker wrote, that the current count of subclasses is around 3 or 4 with not much growth in sight.

Comment: But that doesn't change anything. You can judge, whether to hold objects on single or multiple lists only basing on the context, not on the actual architecture. Sometimes it is justified to group objects which have only one common method and sometimes it is unjustified to hold objects, which have 99% common methods. We have not much data to decide, whether this is a bad design or not.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in several ways.

- Try to `dynamic_cast` to specific class (this is a bruteforce solution, but I'd use it only for interfaces, using it for classes is a kind of code smell. It'll work though.)
- Do something like:

  ```
  class BaseRequest {};
  class DerivedASupportedRequest : public BaseRequest {};
  ```

  Then modify your classes to support the method:

  ```
  // (...)
  void ProcessRequest(const BaseRequest & request);
  ```
- Create a virtual method `bool TryDoSth()` in a base class; `DerivedB` will always return false, while `DerivedA` will implement the required functionality.
- Alternative to above: Create method `Supports(Action action)`, where `Action` is an enum defining possible actions or groups of actions; in such case calling `DoSth()` on class, which does not support given feature should result in thrown exception.
- Base class may have a method `ActionXController * GetControllerForX()`; `DerivedA` will return the actual controller, `DerivedB` will return `nullptr`.
- Similarly, base class can provide method: `BaseController * GetController(Action a)`

You asked, if it is a bad design. I believe, that it depends on how much functionality is common and how much is different. If you have 100 common methods and only one different, it would be weird to hold these data in separate lists. However, if count of different methods is noticeable, consider changing design of your application. This may be a general rule, but there are also exceptions. It's hard to tell without knowing the context.